# Saving pprofile output to a file

Tags: python-2.7, profiling

I am using [pprofile](https://pypi.org/project/pprofile/) to do line profiling on a python script. However, since pprofile also profiles all the modules called by my script, the output is extremely long and gets cut off in the command line. I am only interested in the output of profiling my script, which is at the beginning of the output and thus gets cut off. Is there a way to either:

1. Tell pprofile to only output the results of profiling my script, and none of the other modules, or
2. Save the pprofile output to a file so that I can see the beginning of it?

Comment: Where is the screenshot, where is the error message?

Comment: @VitaliPom There is no error, it's just that the command line you can only scroll back so far, so the information relevant to me is cut off. I don't think a screenshot would illustrate this any better than I did in writing.

Comment: Oh, okay I see you're cool. Sorry, I thought you were commenting on my question with the same comment on purpose, like "who are you to ask math questions". I saw you have 15k points on math.exhange, but now I see you indeed did nlt understand my question. Sorry, I apologies. Will clarify.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Tell pprofile to only output the results of profiling my script, and none of the other modules, or

There are the `--exclude-syspath`, `--exclude some_regex` and `--include some_regex` options. For simple setups they should be rather straightforward to use.

Some background:

- How to match files which do not exist on the filesystem ? Base your regex on the name the code you are interested in appears as in pprofile output. The matched value may look like a filename, but it is actually [co_filename](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html), which can be an arbitrary value.
- Why regexes and not globbing ? As the value may not be a path, I considered that globbing may not be applicable, whereas regexes could fit the task better.

> 2. Save the pprofile output to a file so that I can see the beginning of it?

There is the `-o`/`--output` option to direct the output to a file instead of stdout. Depending on your terminal/shell, you could also use stream redirection operations, typically `>`: `pprofile some_script.py > pprofile_output.txt`.

And going further, on larger programs I recommend using `--format callgrind` and [qcachegrind](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qcachegrindwin/)/[kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) (depending on your OS) to visualize the profiling result in a much more convenient way than plain concatenated source code. Combined with `--zipfile` it has the added benefit of extracting the profiled source code, should you be profiling code on a headless machine and analyzing the output on a different one.